# Ensambling Classification Models

Tags: r, type-conversion, classification

I have made some classification models where `1` means it is the same person, and `0` means they are different.

If I print the head of my predictions it looks the following way:

```
> head(PredictCTree)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
Levels: 0 1
> head(PredictSVM)
    1  1.1  1.2  1.3  1.7 1.14 
    0    0    0    0    0    0 
Levels: 0 1
> head(PredictForest)
    1.212  1.839  1.906  1.951 1.1011 1.1151 
       1      1      1      0      1      1 
Levels: 0 1
```

So if I want to average them and add them up I have to make them numeric, but here is where I am struggling: 
Example:

```
> PredictForest[1]
1.212 
    1 
Levels: 0 1
```

basically I want to add 1 + 0 (for PredictForest and SVM)

```
as.numeric(PredictForest[1])
[1] 2
```

but I end up getting this answer:

```
 > as.numeric(PredictForest[1]) + as.numeric(fitted.results[1] + as.numeric(PredictCTree[1] ))
[1] 4
```

Any suggestions?

My expected output would be:

```
 > as.numeric(PredictForest[1]) + as.numeric(fitted.results[1] + as.numeric(PredictCTree[1] ))
  [1] 1
```

So later on I could divide or give weights in order to test and get the most probable class.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to convert a factor into a number, it'll give you the *number of the level* in the factor. To convert into numbers, you can first run `as.character`, which will safely turn it into a format that you can run `as.numeric` on.

```
test <- as.factor(c(0, 1))
as.numeric(test)
# [1] 1 2
as.numeric(as.character(test))
# [1] 0 1
```

The [R FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f) recommends a different approach for speed

> **7.10 How do I convert factors to numeric?**
>
> It may happen that when reading numeric data into R (usually, when reading in a file), they come in as factors. If f is such a factor object, you can use
>
> `as.numeric(as.character(f))`
>   to get the numbers back. More efficient, but harder to remember, is
>
> `as.numeric(levels(f))[as.integer(f)]`
>   In any case, do not call `as.numeric()` or their likes directly for the task at hand (as `as.numeric()` or `unclass()` give the internal codes).

Comment: Thank you, now I understand!